# Passing an object from view page to Spring controller

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I need to pass a complex object from view page to Spring controller. I am trying to use modelattribute (view page is built using Thymeleaf and HTML).

My problem is, the object is passed as a string instead of an actual object which causes a casting exception at the controller side. In the below, for example "category" is a complex object which contains a list, an array, a string and other objects as variables inside. Category is passed as a string instead of an object itself. How to pass this object to the controller?

```
@Controller
public class QController extends WZController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/refreshfacets")
    public String refreshfacets(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("refreshFacetsRequest") refreshFacetsRequestDTO refreshfacetsrequest) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ProductSearchResult productsearchresult = new ProductSearchResult();
        //super.refreshFacets(request, response, model, productsearchresult);
        return XXXX;
    }
}
```

```
public class refreshFacetsRequestDTO {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Category category;
    private String state;
    private String program;
    private String subject;
    private String year;
    private String price;

    // Constructor, getter, setter methods;
}
```

```
<div th:remove="tag">
    <form method="post" id="form1" th:action="@{/refreshfacets}" th:object="${refreshFacetsRequest}">
    <input type="hidden" id="category" name="category" th:if="${category}" th:value="${category}"/>
    <input type="text" id="state" name="state" th:if="${state}" th:value="${state}"/>
    <input type="text" id="program" name="program" th:if="${program}" th:value="${program}"/>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" th:if="${subject}" th:value="${subject}"/>
    <input type="submit" th:attr="onsubmit=${'doAjaxPost()'}"></input>  
    </form>
</div>
```

Please suggest on this. Any other options other than model attributes to pass the object is also fine. If so please elaborate your other options.

Comment: I don't know what `th:object` does, but spring model-attribute objects only work with spring:form tags.

Comment: @BhashitParikh `th` prefix is for `Thymeleaf`. We can assume that OP is using a `ThymeleafViewResolver`. Model attributes end up in the request attributes, so they are available there as well.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Can u help me on this... model attribute is passed as string, I want it to be object...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want to use `Thymeleaf`'s selector expression with `th:object="${refreshFacetsRequest}"`. The notation for that is `*{someField}`. Change your elements accordingly

```
<input type="hidden" id="category" name="category" th:if="*{category}" th:value="*{category}"/>
```

The above would resolve to `${refreshFacetsRequest.category}`.

**EDIT**

Going from View to Controller, what you're doing is making your browser send an HTTP request to an HTTP server (your servlet container). There is no notion of objects here. The `<input>` field with name `category` will be passed as a request parameter in the HTTP POST.

Spring is usually smart enough to transform from request parameters to objects, but it needs some information. Is `Category` an enum? If it is, Spring will attempt to use `Category.valueOf(requestParam)` to convert it. If it is a class, it will try to use other request params which have names that match the fields of the `Category` class to instantiate it and set it in the `refreshFacetsRequestDTO` object that you've declared with `@ModelAttribute`.

I don't quite understand what you mean by *retrieved value is a String value i*. Is there an error message that comes along?

Comment: No.. U misundetstood my question.. Sorry for my bad english.. Ur answer works when pass a value from controller to view page but I want to pass value from view page to controller.. there ${category} will retrieve value from request attribute category and store it in ${refreshFacetsRequest} model attribute which can be retrieved in controller.. this is my idea.. My prob is retrieved value is a String value instead of object itself (category object)...